# Android - AndEngine Apply Force

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm using AndEngine and Box2d in android application.
What do I have to do so that when pushing the "leftArrow" and "rightArrow" buttons, the player doesn't start moving too fast because of the too frequent call of the "Update Handler" method? I want the player to move constantly with the same speed.

```
//same for leftArrow
Sprite rightArrow = new Sprite(...) {
  @Override
  public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
    float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
      goRight = true;
    }
    else if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
      goRight = false;
    }

    return true;
  }
};

private IUpdateHandler  UpdateHandler = new IUpdateHandler(){
  @Override
  public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

    if(goLeft) {
      playerBody.applyForce(-50, 0, body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y);
    }
    if(goRight){
      playerBody.applyForce(50, 0, body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use setLinearVelocity instead of applyForce. It should work